# FreeBSD ipfw firewall_type

Tags: firewall, freebsd

I'm trying to create my own firewall script inside of FreeBSD and I'm running in a bit problems, I was wondering if someone done something smilier and could show me an example?

```
su-3.2# grep ^firewall /etc/rc.conf 
firewall_enable="YES"       # Set to YES to enable firewall functionality
firewall_type="/etc/ipfw.rules"
firewall_quiet="YES"        # Set to YES to suppress rule display
firewall_logging="YES"      # Set to YES to enable events logging
firewall_logdeny="YES"      # Set to YES to log default denied incoming
su-3.2# cat /etc/ipfw.rules 
${fwcmd} add 65000 pass all from any to any
su-3.2# /etc/rc.d/ipfw restart
/etc/rc.d/ipfw: DEBUG: checkyesno: firewall_enable is set to YES.
/etc/rc.d/ipfw: DEBUG: checkyesno: firewall_enable is set to YES.
/etc/rc.d/ipfw: DEBUG: run_rc_command: doit: ipfw_stop 
net.inet.ip.fw.enable: 1 -> 0
/etc/rc.d/natd: DEBUG: checkyesno: natd_enable is set to NO.
/etc/rc.d/ipfw: DEBUG: checkyesno: firewall_enable is set to YES.
/etc/rc.d/ipfw: DEBUG: run_rc_command: start_precmd: ipfw_prestart 
/etc/rc.d/ipfw: DEBUG: checkyesno: dummynet_enable is set to NO.
/etc/rc.d/ipfw: DEBUG: checkyesno: firewall_nat_enable is set to NO.
/etc/rc.d/ipfw: DEBUG: load_kld: ipfw kernel module already loaded.
/etc/rc.d/ipfw: DEBUG: run_rc_command: doit: ipfw_start 
/etc/rc.d/natd: DEBUG: checkyesno: natd_enable is set to NO.
Line 1: bad command `${fwcmd}'
Firewall rules loaded.
/etc/rc.d/ipfw: DEBUG: checkyesno: firewall_logging is set to YES.
Firewall logging enabled.
net.inet.ip.fw.enable: 0Read from remote host XXXXX.XXX: Connection reset by peer
Connection to XXXXX.XXX closed.
mbp:~ alexus$
```

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: If this is a new setup you may want to look at pf instead of ipfw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lose the `${fwcmd}`. Your file is being provided to ipfw as an argument.

```
ipfw [-cfnNqS] [-p preproc [preproc-flags]] pathname
```

> To ease configuration, rules can be
>   put into a file which is processed
>   using ipfw as shown in the last
>   synopsis line.  An absolute pathname
>   must be used. The file will be read
>   line by line and applied as arguments
>   to the ipfw utility.

Try running `ipfw /etc/ipfw.rules`

Comment: do I need something like

add 65000 pass all from any to any

at the end of file to make it similar to "open" ? or is it going add it on it's own?

Comment: It will not add anything, and at the end the default rule will be (usually it is deny; check `sysctl net.inet.ip.fw.default_to_accept`).

Answer (score 2):

**Tip:** You should enter rules to IPFW from a rc.d script (ex: /usr/local/etc/rc.d/ipfw.sh), don't use /etc/ipfw.rules , thats not flexible at all

Answer (score 0):

basically, do what gleb said.

if you want to specify a script in `rc.conf`, you should rename your file, and use something like: `firewall_script="/etc/ipfw.conf"`

see `/etc/defaults/rc.conf` for more info.

also, `${fwcmd}` needs to be defined; usually it's something like:

```
fwcmd="/sbin/ipfw"
```

see here for more info:
http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/firewalls-ipfw.html